# ego-centric(structure hole) measures in social networking analysis in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have an adjacency matrix, from which I want to find the ego-centric(structure hole) measure using the package `egonet`.

My problem is that when I apply the function `index.egonet` it only gives me 
the aggregated results for the matrix while I want node-node measures. My adjacency matrix looks like this

```
  m4
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 6
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
3 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0   }}--> subset orsample of my matrix 
8 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the required results are

```
          EffSize Efficie Constra Hierarc Indirec
          ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
  1    1 1991.362   0.816   0.003   0.182   0.944
  2   23 2167.309   0.840   0.003   0.137   0.956
  3  134 2041.932   0.821   0.003   0.160   0.955
  4  582 2206.219   0.828   0.003   0.160   0.971
  5  610 2168.594   0.814   0.003   0.195   0.970
  6  762 1697.840   0.824   0.003   0.172   0.877
  7  881 2189.964   0.816   0.004   0.204   0.975
  8  901 2241.622   0.810   0.004   0.222   0.985
  9  983 2026.767   0.822   0.003   0.156   0.9
```

Dyadic Redundancy(table) and constraint table 
Any help will highly be appreciated.